# Get installed and deleted application using Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'm really new to Android programming.
I'm trying to get a list of my deleted and installed apps.

I found out that I can utilize the `PackageManager` class and get the installed applications with the `getInstalledApplications()` method. But I'm not sure how to find the deleted apps.

I know that Google Play Store keeps this information (I can see it in my phone). But I have no idea how to access this list.

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm not sure how to find the deleted apps.

You can't.

> but I have no idea how to access this list.

You can't. Even if that data is saved locally on the device (and I don't know that it is), that data is private to the Play Store app. The Play Store app does not have any APIs for third-party apps, like yours, to rummage through the apps that the user has uninstalled.

Also, please bear in mind that there are many devices that do not have the Play Store at all, in addition to uninstalled apps that were never installed via the Play Store in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this information is on Google's database and not in the phone somewhere. So, it is not accessible for any app.